# Direct X and WPF integration

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics, 3d, directx

THis might be a very vague questions and apologies if posted in the wrong forum.
But I am starting out on a project involving C# and WPF. This project requires some really serious heavy graphics, want the final result to be as smooth as an iPad graphics. So, now my question is, is WPF upto the task? if not can I do something about it? Hardware boost? or if not is there anyway to leverage on Direct X? or third party libraries?

Comment: Does Your requirement mention also 3D graphics or only 2D? Smothness is not worth to question, if You use 2D. This runs already smooth.

Comment: is playing video 2D?

Comment: @JackyBoi: Absolutly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As everything reagarding to 2D graphics in WPF is based on `DirectX` calls, you will probably not find any faster way except using `DirectX` directly.

To my understanding everything regarding graphics on an IPad/IPhone seems faster compared to other devices is based on the fact that the rendering on those devices is done in a dedicated thread.

As long as you are not going to use Windows Forms (where everything is rendered using the CPU) you should be fine ;-)

Comment: so is there anyway to force use graphics card?

Comment: Everything concerning `WPF` is based on using `DirectX` which is based on using the graphics card. I guess there would be no way to NOT use it ;-)

Comment: Oh right got it! tks that clears much of the things.

Comment: any idea if windows embedded has the same features as the desktop version?

Comment: @MarkusSafar If everything concerning WPF uses directX and available graphics card, does WPF3D also use DirectX and graphics card?